# How to encode manipulated categorical variable back to original values?

Tags: python

I have a categorical variable in my data frame. Then, I encoded it in order to pass into a neural network. However, my final visualization graph shows me of course still the encoded/numerical values for the categorical variable and I am having difficulties mapping it back to its original value. 
Print Format can be: jpg, png, ico, heic, pdf, word, etc.

I used this command to encode my categorical variable "Print Format" into numerical values first:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for x in df.columns:
    if df[x].dtypes=='object':
       df[x]=le.fit_transform(df[x].astype(str))
```

Then, I wanted to revert it back by using this code right before the final visualization:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for x in df.columns:
    if df[x].dtypes=='object':
       df[x]=le.inverse_transform(df[x].astype(str))
```

...but the visualization STILL does not show the original values. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the implemented function

```
le.inverse_transform(df[x])
```

[Documentation for inverse transform and Label Encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.inverse_transform)

Comment: This is the code I added right before the final visualization: `le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for x in df.columns:
    if df[x].dtypes=='object':
       df[x]=le.inverse_transform(df[x].astype(str))` But the visualization STILL does not show the original values. Why?

Comment: Can somebody help please?